# How to migrate child instance creation to Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, migration, vuejs3

I’m migrating an app from Vue 2.6 to 3.2, currently in migration build, trying to get rid of all the warnings. I can’t figure out how to rewrite the child instance creation.

Current code that successfully mounts the instance/component programmatically under Vue 2:

```js
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'
const Ctor = Vue.extend(ChildComponent)
;(childApp = new Ctor({
  router: this.$router,
  store: this.$store
})).$mount()
```

I tried the following Vue 3 code, it renders successfully, but shows some warnings:

```js
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'
childApp = createApp(ChildComponent)
childApp.use(this.$router)
childApp.use(this.$store)
childApp.mount('#child-container')
```

The warnings:

```
[Vue warn]: Component "RouterLink" has already been registered in target app.
[Vue warn]: Component "RouterView" has already been registered in target app.
```

Here is another Vue 3 version of the code that I tried, this one fails to render and displays an error:

```js
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'
childApp = createApp({
    router: this.$router,
    store: this.$store,
    render: () => h(ChildComponent),
})
childApp.mount('#child-container')
```

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_modulesNamespaceMap')
```

I'm using the programmatic approach because it allows to preserve the single instance of the component across different layouts that we're mounting it to.

How do I make it to work under Vue 3 without warnings? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think re-using `this.$router` and `this.$store` may be the problem. Try importing the router and store and use that. Once instance is imported and already used in one Vue instance, it can not be re-used in another Vue instance.

Comment: I think I need instantiated version of router. If I just import the router and attempt to use it directly, the imported object doesn't have the needed methods like `.$push()`. Also it's missing `$this.$route` property which I'm currently using in the child app.

What did work though is a workaround in form of `childApp.config.globalProperties.$router = this.$router` (and the same for `$route` and `$store`) immediately after creating the child app instance. Do you think there is a better way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: No, the Vuex router should be imported the way the documentation explains.With 'use'. This would also be future proof for your code. Nice to hear you found another way.

Comment: Not really, later on I discovered that `$route` added to the child app's component this way is not reactive